# toDataURL not working on android browsers

Tags: android, html, canvas

I have an image that the user drew on a canvas and i want to save that image on the server.

These lines work well on my ipad but not on my android(ver 2.3.3) browser:

```
var testCanvas = document.getElementById("sketchpad");  
var canvasData = testCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

If i alert canvasData i only get:

> data:,

Am I missing something? Is it possible to do on android or should i be looking at other methods, plugins, etc?

Comment: Most likely unsupported on your Android version (please mention it)

Comment: yes, that's what I was thinking. It's 2.3.3

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901 Although it works on my android tablet as well looks like it wont work on older phones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't supported in your version (i think it's only supported in ICS), have a look at this issue reported

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16829

There is supposed to be some sort of JavaScript implementation to add support for it, but i haven't tried it myself

http://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the js method and it works. It's slow (14 sec-2+ min to create a 400x800 image from a phone) but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @user971727: Have you found the better approach for the above todataurl-png-js? Because I also can use it but its taking too much time..

Comment: No I haven't. Sorry I'm getting back to you so late, I stopped working on this project for a while. I started it all over again and decided to go native, because canvas is more responsive this way. So if you can, try it.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately toDataURL() only work on android 3.2 or above version.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative implementation that we have used successfully on multiple Android handsets without modification is described in this blog post:

http://jimdoescode.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/trials-and-tribulations-with-html5.html

This uses the toDataURL method if it works correctly, and if not uses a javascript jpg encoding library to produce the image.