# canvas.toDataURL does not result in image/jpeg data

Tags: android, cordova, html5-canvas, base64

I am trying to save html5 canvas data to server using base64 + phonegap 2.5.

**platforms** : windows phone 7 and 8 , Android and IOS.

Basic need for image resizing is to optimize data before send over server.

I am having issue with android platform base64 response method which are as follows

**Problems** :

1. Android 4.2 : I wrote this code `c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");`   but i got this `data:image/png;base64`
2. Android 2.3 : I am unable to retrieve base64 data

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: jalsa karrr milan bytes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- **Android 2.3 : I am unable to retrieve base64 data**

canvas.toDataURL is not supported in old Android versions.

There's a js fix for that but performance might not be very good:
https://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/

Check here for more info:
[toDataURL not working on android browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488033/todataurl-not-working-on-android-browsers)

- **Android 4.2 : I wrote this code c.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); but i got this data:image/png;base64**

Android 4.x supports canvas.toDataURL; however, it doesn't support jpeg format (if you ask for a jpeg, it will return a png).

More details:
https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/33

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay Luis. it helps me a lot.

Comment: chrome on android 4.1+ seems to give "image/jpeg" if you ask for it

Answer (score 2):

Only `image/png` is supported by old browsers (WebKits) and this is the only codec you can rely to be present. `img/jpeg` get added later on and is still not supported by many browsers.

For Android 2.3: try if you can do it in vanilla browser. If it works there then it is a PhoneGap issue and should be reported to the authors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update. could u please help me on this.
Actually I am trying to reduce the image size using canvas. so what I am doing is loading the image on canvas and redrawing it into 300x300 dimension and then fetching the base64 string of the canvas. and the canvas is also 310x310 pixels. but when the generated base64 string is larger then the base64 string of origional image generated using android device.

Comment: It would be better if you open another question with this specific information, so that the context of discussion stays clean and searchable

Comment: _“but when the generated base64 string is larger then the base64 string of origional image”_ – that might be because the original image (jpg?) was saved using a low quality factor, whereas you get your new image with a higher quality. You could try setting the quality via second parameter.