# Why jpeg dataURL is a whole black image?

Tags: html5-canvas, jpeg, data-url

When I do

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.open(data,"My Image","width=500,height=400");
```

I accurately get whatever was in the canvas but  when i do

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
window.open(data,"My Image","width=500,height=400");
```

I am getting a whole black image. Can any one explain why is so? or whether I am doing something wrong? I am using Google Chrome by the way.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495221/canvas-todataurl-does-not-result-in-image-jpeg-data) explains it. But `image/png` is always better because its a lossless format, I suggest you use it.

Comment: @Havenard yes I agree to you that png is better but the problem is I need to use jsPDF to print a PDF of my canvas image, jsPDF addImage() function only accepts a jpeg image dataURL, I tried to give it png dataURL just to check but it gave me error. jsPDF is printing that black image to a pdf file, I have to do something with the dataURL