# Why toDataURL Does Not Get Canvas Content on Mobile?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, mobile, canvas

I'm trying to get an image from a canvas, it worked on pc browsers, but not on mobile (I tested on an iPhone in Safari)...

Here is the code:

```
$('#draw').click(function() {            
    $('#drawing').css("visibility", "visible");         
    var drawing = document.getElementById("drawing");
    var con = drawing.getContext("2d");         
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://www.deque.com/wbcntnt928/wp-content/dquploads/jquery_logo.png";
    img.onload = function() {                
        con.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 250, 250);
        //Generate Image
        var drawing = document.getElementById("drawing");
        var dataURL = drawing.toDataURL(); //Does nothing on mobile, not even an error
        document.getElementById("result").src = dataURL;
    };                  

});
```

Any hint of why?

Comment: what does it return then?

Comment: @fiddler, it doesn't return anything... Nothing happens, I try to show the content with an alert, but does not show, because it stops at toDataUrl line...

Comment: I just saw that it is not working on Safari, it works on Chrome and the Samsung browser for S3... Safari can't resolve toDataURL, I can't figure out why yet...

Comment: And, I tested on iOS 6, and worked on Safari! It is no working on iOS 7...

Comment: @CarinaPilar Do you have any solution for this problem yet?

Comment: @confile, actually I was working on something to show the differences between mobile platforms, so my point was to show that this doesn't work on iOS 7 and works on iOS 6... So I didn't go deeper to find a solution... For me, with the code I shared, just doesn't work on iOS 7.

Comment: @CarinaPilar I tried this https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob but if you try it from iOS7 I always get file size 0. Here is a jsfiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/h7zV3/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Tested on HTC Desire with Android 2.3, HTC One with Android 4.0 and iPhone 7s ... I run over the `toDataURL()` but only get "data:," as output.

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488033/todataurl-not-working-on-android-browsers) it's not supported by Android, dunno about iOS7 but it seems it isn't either.

Btw. is there a reason for calling `var drawing = document.getElementById("drawing");` twice?

Comment: No reason to call that twice... Yeah, I guess it's not supported... =/

Comment: Try much smaller canvas dimensions. I think it runs out of memory. I was getting "data:," back as well trying to parse photos from the camera - as soon as I shrunk the canvas, I started to get data back.

Comment: Well, back when I answered it wasn't supported. Should be by now as far as I've heard, though there were complaints about performance. @CarinaPilar would have to try it again ;)