# Canvas.toDataURL not working on mobile Safari iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas

I tried the following. I created an `<img>` from an svg image. Then I draw it on a canvas and finally I exported it as PNG and set the resulting PNG as a new `<img>`. It works well on Android, Chrome, Safari, FireFox. But, `canvas.toDataUrl()` is not working on mobile Safari on iOS. It is only working when you don't use SVG images on the canvas.

Here is the code I use for testing:

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<img id="image2">
```

```js
var mydiv  = document.getElementById('mydiv'),
    image2 = document.getElementById('image2');

image2.crossOrigin="anonymous";

var image3 = new Image();
mydiv.appendChild(image3);
image3.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = image3.width;
  canvas.height = image3.height;

  ctx.drawImage(image3,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  image2.src = dataUrl;
}
image3.crossOrigin="anonymous";
image3.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47067729/sticker4.svg";
```

I created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/ZqJYG/

The problem occurs only when you run it on iOS. It does not run on mobile Safari and not on mobile Chrome.

**Is there a workaround for this problem?**

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972038/why-todataurl-does-not-get-canvas-content-on-mobile and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495221/canvas-todataurl-does-not-result-in-image-jpeg-data

Comment: To be sure: does your JSFiddle work for you on Chrome or Firefox? I cannot test because my company blocks requests to DropBox. Further, are you sure that you're not hitting cross-domain security issues, where drawing the remote SVG to your canvas is tainting it?

Comment: @Phrogz yes it works on desktop Chrome and FF. Any other idea how to solve it.

Comment: If I had an idea I would already have posted it.

Comment: I'm also face the same problem. my code perfectly working in desktop, but the same code is not working for iPad safari. How to resolve the issue

Answer (score 5):

This may or may not be the same issue, but I was getting "data:," back from this call on iOS (worked everywhere else) and managed to solve the problem by dramatically reducing the size of the canvas. I think it was running out of memory either loading the image or returning the string, and dealing with it in a particularly useless fashion.

Comment: The max size of our canvas was 2000 pixels, but when we lowered it to 1500 it worked. We had problems on <= iPhones 5.

Comment: Glad to see Safari sorted this out. Found in mobile Safari at iOS 8.3. Later  versions didn't seem to have this memory issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think your browser may not support it . see the following.

http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas

```
iPhone 3GS        - Mobile Safari 4.0.5
iPhone 4          - Mobile Safari 4.0.5
iPhone 4s         - Mobile Safari 5.1
iPad 1 / 3.2.2    - Mobile Safari 4.0.4
iPad 2 / 4.3.3    - Mobile Safari 5.02
iPad 2 / 5.0      - Mobile Safari 5.1
iPad 3 / 5.1      - Mobile Safari 5.1
iPhone 5 / 6.0    - Mobile Safari 6.0
iPad 4 / 6.0      - Mobile Safari 6.0
```

You can also test your browser support by using the following code:

```
function supportsToDataURL()
{
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    var data = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    return (data.indexOf("data:image/png") == 0);
}
```

Hope this helps.