# Use canvas inside a Handlebars template?

Tags: jquery, canvas, handlebars.js

What is the best way to insert a `<canvas>` drawing into a handlebars template? See the below example. My first try was the `canvas-inline` helper function, which creates a canvas object using JavaScsript then returns it. Sadly all I see in the template is "[object HTMLCanvasElement]". Handlebars expects an HTML text string!

So, my first question is: is there a way to return a ready-made DOM object to a Handlebars object? If not, is it an easy hack, or is it totally against the way Handlebars works under-the-hood?

My second try was the `canvas-timer` helper function. This just returns a `<canvas>` string, but then uses a 100ms timeout to go and add the canvas contents afterwards. This works, but I don't like the fact that Mr. Fragility has now joined the team (wearing his "I Love Magic Numbers" t-shirt).

So, if the answers to my first two questions were "no" and "no", is there a good way to use this latter approach, but get rid of the timer and the arbitrary 100ms guess? I.e. so the Javascript code will run just when the `<canvas>` element appears, not before, not after.  NOTE: I want something encapsulated in the helper function.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HCQSt/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Handlebars: canvas test</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/handlebars.js"></script>

<!--- ******************** TEMPLATES ********************  -->

<script id="test-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<h3>Hello {{world}}</h3>
{{{canvas-inline col}}}
{{{canvas-timer col}}}
</script>

<!--- ******************** ************ ********************  -->

<script language="javascript">
Handlebars.registerHelper("canvas-inline", function(col) {
var canvas  = document.createElement('canvas');
if(canvas){
    console.log(canvas);
    canvas.width=128;canvas.height=128;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    ctx.fillRect(0,80,128,16);
    ctx.fillRect(16,0,32,32);
    ctx.fillRect(80,0,32,32);
    }
else console.log("no canvas object");
return canvas;
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("canvas-timer", function(col) {
setTimeout(function(){
    //var canvas    = document.createElement('canvas');
    var canvas  = $('#xxx')[0];
    if(canvas){
        console.log(canvas);
        canvas.width=128;canvas.height=128;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = col;
        ctx.fillRect(0,80,128,16);
        ctx.fillRect(16,0,32,32);
        ctx.fillRect(80,0,32,32);
        }
    else console.log("no canvas object");
    },100);
return '<canvas id="xxx"></canvas>';
});


var T=Handlebars.compile ( $("#test-template").html() );

$(function(){   //onReady
var obj={ world:"Blue-Green Planet", col:"#f33" };
$('<div class="view" id="test1">').append(T(obj)).appendTo('#views');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Handlebars: canvas test</h1>

<div id="views"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S. If your questions was "Why do would you want to do that?", my answer is "QR codes". A QR code of a URL being given to the template.  (In this particular case I have a tables workaround, but I'm sure that won't always be the case.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The helpers are mostly there to generate content that goes in your view, so when helpers are triggered, this is before the view is inserted into the page. When your helper depends on the view elements existing you run into timing issues. (Thus the reason why your magic timeout works).

An Alternative is to use an image instead of a canvas, and let the helper generate the data url.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/L7TqJ/2/

```
<script id="test-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h3>Hello {{world}}</h3>
    <img src="{{{generateQRCode col}}}"/>
</script>


Handlebars.registerHelper("generateQRCode", function (col) {
    var canvas = window.document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 128;
    canvas.height = 128;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 80, 128, 16);
    ctx.fillRect(16, 0, 32, 32);
    ctx.fillRect(80, 0, 32, 32);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
});

var T = Handlebars.compile($("#test-template").html());

$(function () { //onReady
    var obj = {
        world: "Blue-Green Planet",
        col: "green"
    };
    $('<div class="view" id="test1">').append(T(obj)).appendTo('#views');
});
```

**Think this is still too messy?**

You may also want to try using ember, which uses handlebars for it's view layer and also triggers events when a view is inserted.

Edit: I realized one of my proposed solutions could be put into a helper.

Comment: Brilliant, that was just what I was looking for. By the way, rather than putting `<img>` in the template, I had the helper function return this: `return '<img src="'+canvas.toDataURL()+'" />';` (That way I can switch to an alternative approach without altering the template.)

Comment: BTW, while canvas (with the timer) works with Android 2.3, `toDataURL()` needs Android 3.2 or higher:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/10488033/841830  (that URL shows some apparently slow workarounds if you really must do it this way).

Comment: If you need to support browsers that don't support toDataURL() I would recommend calling the canvas drawing function after the view has been inserted into the page. It's messier outside of the helper, but that polyfill is probably very slow.