# How do I convert a png to a base64 string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, base64

I've tried several different options, so many I've lost track of them all. I'm making an AJAX request and the response is of `Content-Type: image/png`, and the contents are the actual image.

I would absolutely love to display the image, but nothing seems to work the way I want:

```
// imgdata contains a string that looks like this: "�PNG..."
var img = document.createElement('img');

// no good
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));

// also no good
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(encodeURIComponent(data));

// also no good
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa($.map(d, function(x){ return x.charCodeAt(0); }))
```

I've tried a few other things, but still no dice.

Is there any simple (or even complciated) way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: This question has already been asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: @Sparkup that involves the canvas element which is *not* just Javascript. For IE it's [only supported as far back as 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas). If you have to support 8 (or earlier) that solution just won't work.

Comment: It also appears that `toData` [doesn't always work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488033/todataurl-not-working-on-android-browsers)

Comment: The other solution is to use `FileReader` which is even less-well supported.

Comment: Ok seems it hasn't been answered, so sorry. I have made myself useful however by adding an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't done with `base64` but with `blob`, but you'll get exactly the same result:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var img = document.getElementById('image');
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            img.src = url.createObjectURL(this.response);
        }
    }
    // Relative path because : 
    // No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present...
    xhr.open('GET', '/img/logo.png');
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
```

**Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/sparkup/sp4cukee/**

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving this file via node.js or PHP you could always write the file to disk in temporary location server-side, serve it, and then immediately delete it afterwards.

```
var tempFile = 'path/to/file.jpg';

// Write the file to disk
fs.writeFile(tempFile, base64versionOfPhoto, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        res.header("Content-Type","application/json");
        return res.send(JSON.stringify(err));   
    } else {
        // Pipe the jpg to the user
        res.header("Content-Type","image/jpeg");

        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(tempFile);
        readStream.pipe(res, {end: false});

        readStream.on("end", function () {
            res.end();

            // Delete the file
            fs.unlink(tempFile, function (err) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: *note* it doesn't necessarily have to be node.js or PHP, those were meant to be examples. My code provided is node.js btw

Comment: Hmmm. That might be a workaround. I'm using Java, ugh, or I'd just convert things server side

Comment: I came across this problem when I was trying to display photos from an LDAP server, which were in base64. After numerous attempts like you, I found that the best way was to have the server "create" the file long enough for it to be served to the client. You should definitely be able to do something similar from Java.